# knockout js How to trigger an event when dropdown selected index is changed

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am trying to trigger an alert message based on my selected Item in my drop down list.

On our original project, we am trying to to make the change in selected index to trigger checking if that selected index is already existing and currently active.

HTML:

```
<select 
    data-bind="options:vmList, 
               optionsCaption: 'Selecting...',
               optionsText: 'Hello',                
               optionsValue: 'Hello1',
               value: getSelected">                                    
</select>

<span data-bind="text:getSelected"></span>
```

ViewModel:

```
$(function()
{
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
});

var VM = 
{
    vmList:ko.observableArray([{Hello:"1",Hello1:"2"}]),
    Hello: ko.observable(),

    getSelected: ko.observable(),

    Hello: function()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }
}
```

i was trying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677431/change-observable-value-on-dropdown-change-knockout-js) but it didnt work for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change observable value on dropdown change Knockout Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677431/change-observable-value-on-dropdown-change-knockout-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event using `event: {change: selectedValueChanged}` binding. It uses the [`event`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding.

Note that instead of the `event` property you might expect normally, Knockout provides you with the context as a parameter to the event handler.

```js
$(function()
{
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
});

var VM = 
{
    vmList:ko.observableArray([{Hello:"1",Hello1:"1"}, {Hello:"2",Hello1:"2"}, {Hello:"3",Hello1:"3"}]),
    Hello: ko.observable(),

    getSelected: ko.observable(),

    Hello: function()
    {
        alert('hello');
    },
    selectedValueChanged: function(context) {
      console.log(context.getSelected());
      
      if(context.getSelected()) {
        alert('You selected: ' + context.getSelected());
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select 
    data-bind="options:vmList, 
               optionsCaption: 'Selecting...',
               optionsText: 'Hello',                
               optionsValue: 'Hello1',
               value: getSelected,
               event: {change: selectedValueChanged}">                                    
</select>

<span data-bind="text:getSelected"></span>
```

Comment: For some reason the console.log shows me the previously selected item in the dropdown not the newly selected one.

Comment: @corix010 That's actually because of mismatch in values and text. Check now.